# Can someone tell me if I can do OpenCL from my CLinfo log?

Tags: opencl

So, this is the clinfo.log I get running CLinfo

```
  Platform Name:                 Intel(R) OpenCL
Number of devices:               1
  Device Type:               CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
  Device ID:                 32902
  Max compute units:             2
  Max work items dimensions:         3
    Max work items[0]:           1024
    Max work items[1]:           1024
    Max work items[2]:           1024
  Max work group size:           1024
  Preferred vector width char:       1
  Preferred vector width short:      1
  Preferred vector width int:        1
  Preferred vector width long:       1
  Preferred vector width float:      1
  Preferred vector width double:         1
  Max clock frequency:           2930Mhz
  Address bits:              14757395255531667488
  Max memory allocation:             536838144
  Image support:                 Yes
  Max number of images read arguments:   480
  Max number of images write arguments:  480
  Max image 2D width:            16384
  Max image 2D height:           16384
  Max image 3D width:            2048
  Max image 3D height:           2048
  Max image 3D depth:            2048
  Max samplers within kernel:        480
  Max size of kernel argument:       3840
  Alignment (bits) of base address:      1024
  Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:128
  Single precision floating point capability
    Denorms:                 Yes
    Quiet NaNs:              Yes
    Round to nearest even:           Yes
    Round to zero:               No
    Round to +ve and infinity:       No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:     No
  Cache type:                Read/Write
  Cache line size:               64
  Cache size:                3145728
  Global memory size:            2147352576
  Constant buffer size:          131072
  Max number of constant args:       480
  Local memory type:             Global
  Local memory size:             32768
  Error correction support:          0
  Profiling timer resolution:        350
  Device endianess:              Little
  Available:                 Yes
  Compiler available:            Yes
  Execution capabilities:                
    Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
    Execute native function:         Yes
  Queue properties:              
    Out-of-Order:                Yes
    Profiling :              Yes
  Platform ID:               00531298
  Name:                  Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7500  @ 2.93GHz
  Vendor:                    Intel(R) Corporation
  Driver version:                3.0.1.15216
  Profile:                   FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                   OpenCL 1.2 (Build 80752)
  Extensions:                cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_intel_printf cl_ext_device_fission cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_intel_dx9_media_sharing cl_khr_dx9_media_sharing cl_khr_d3d11_sharing
```

Now, if I understand correcly, the following lines :

```
Compiler available:          Yes
  Execution capabilities:                
    Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
    Execute native function:         Yes
  Queue properties:              
    Out-of-Order:                Yes
    Profiling :              Yes
```

mean I do have OpenCL capabilities.

But, when I try and use MAthematica's functionality of OpenCL it says I can't do OpenCL.

This isn't a question about Mathematica, but rather a question of whether or not I have OpenCL capabilities at all.

So, can someone check the log, because most of it is Greek to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  This shows that you definitely have a functioning Intel OpenCL CPU implementation.  The implementation is for the OpenCL 1.2 spec (fairly new).  Not sure what Mathematica requires of why it can't find OpenCL.

Maybe try out some other OpenCL enabled programs (from samples or something).  But I think figuring out if Mathematica supports the Intel version of OpenCL might be a good direction.

Side Note: https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html has the programatic definition of some of those symbols CLInfo is using (CLInfo probably lists similar information too).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have a OpenCL compliant device. But i doesn't mean that any application using OpenCL will run on it.
There are a lot of reasons why a application would tells you that you can't use OCL such as:

- The application queries a specific type of OCL device such as CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU but you only have a CPU OCL compliant, so the app tells you No.
- Same that above but instead searches for a specific extension that you device doesn't support.
- Basically any info that you gathered in you log can be query by an OCL app, and it might not like some numbers (not enough local memory, etc). Here I doubt it's the reason...